# Where in Germany was this photo taken?

Tags: germany, history

This photo, in all likelihood, shows a place in Germany in the 1920s. Where could it be?

[image: grayscale photograph of a likely German town square]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivOY-DZOOlpgnBTM4YOYrziYT5CH6e_1h5PN9sKOn1s5cmMpvrX83sJnI4omcGRHwfECikEwTFtAJKksRt72Es2uGM_147Z-o7IaGGH5VaJIFw4XQtX6xBsZyll4hnzlfhqx5KPFmGC4cQmxC8r-0m3NpdkML8a1EPpIESeBIQb680kT6qxHsi5LG5zs5xEFZrmgWlZX5iuazSRy9pQzCcKfLVwxhonuF_1itapc4sVmawr77nAGMq-Ut2r00Xo9kUiHs-f-ErfxDuOh0XGcSZG0EJBTM5h9HriGVCWsMFhJVk96xMPWbe4IGkHoTU5oGEpjK88-e9vEXxOj-vZwIhE708Ojaosw) brought up a Wikipedia page for [Uslar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uslar), Germany, which includes a picture of a building that looks to be the same as in your photo.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Das alte Rathaus der Stadt Uslar. Erbaut 1476.